# override a field in a document in firebase instead of updating it

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to update a field in a firebase document but it does not update it make another field with the same spelling there is anyone knows the problem

Answer (score 2):

There are two method you can update your data document.

1. update() method but if the document doesnt exist yet it will throw an error

```
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("collectionPath")
        .doc("docId")
        .update(data);
```

2. set() method, if the document still not exist it will create a new document. Else update the current document but you need to set `merge = true` so it will only update the changes and not rewrite it

```
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("collectionPath")
        .doc("docId")
        .set(data, SetOptions(merge: true));
```